# Developing installation packages in Linux

Tags: linux, installation-package

I need information about making installation packages for Linux. I want to make simple package, containing executable + shared libraries, and SDK package for programmers, with executables and h-files. How can this be done? Articles, books, samples - everything that can help to learn this issue.

Comment: this is more for superuser.com - depends on type of package system used - deb, rpm, tgz or tar.gz etc.

Comment: Are you talking about coding your own package with a make file and then converting it to an rpm or dep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the linux system. For Ubuntu/Debian, you could read the [Ubuntu Packaging Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide). For RedHat, here is the [RPM guide from Fedora](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/drafts/rpm-guide-en/).

Globally, take the linux distrib of your choice, see how they package, and reproduce.

Answer (score 2):

I have to admit I've never actually done this myself, but I hope I can get you started. There's different packaging standards for different Linux distributions.

For Debian-based distros like Ubuntu, you'll want to create a .deb file. [This article](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/336) explains how.

For RedHat-based distributions, you'll create an RPM. Developerworks has what looks like a pretty in-depth guide [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-rpm1/).

Answer (score 1):

almost any distribution system out there has an package generator - try checkinstall for Debian-based (Ubuntu etc.) DEB packages - just run it and it will do all the stuff required for you.

Same thing works for Slackware TGZ.

Comment: checkinstall is good for tracking what has been installed, but doesn't create really "proper" package.

Comment: well, it actually does. it even allows you to set description and other meta data of package.

Answer (score 1):

You want to make packages for every distro (Debian (*.deb), Redhat (*.rpm),Slackware(*tgz/*.txz) ? If yes, maybe you can learn howto make binary package for all distro. I think, the solution (creating packages for every distro) is not very easy task for developer. I prefer give src to community and then community make specific distro packages :D

Or if you want to make *portable installer* to all distro, if yes maybe you can try [Makeself](http://megastep.org/makeself/). It's very easy to create *binary* packages with *.sh or *.bin extension with [Makeself](http://megastep.org/makeself/), create your installer with this then upload to your public server. End user can install with :
1. Give execute permission to your installer like this *chmod +x my-installer.bin*
2. Execute the installer like this *./my-installer.bin* :)

You know NetBeans IDE ? They use the same technique for they installer :)